# Wordpress admin email update on user meta table aswell

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

I want to update email when updating Profile in wp_admin for wp_user in wp_usermeta table's email aswell. I tried below under user-edit.php in wp-admin folder but it does not seem to work...

```
<?php $wpdb->query( "UPDATE wp_usermeta SET meta_value = '".$_POST['email']."' WHERE user_id = '$userid' AND meta_key = 'email'" ); ?>
```

Is there a good solution for this?

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest the following.

```
<?php
$wpdb->update(
    $wpdb->usermeta,
    array(
        'meta_value' => $_POST['email'])
    ),
    array(
        'user_id' => $userid,
        'meta_key' => 'email'
    )
);
?>
```